# How to test if speaker is playing the sound programatically?

Tags: audio, sound-card, speakers

Is there a way to determine if speakers are playing the sound, given that there is no microphone to detect this.

I have an embedded system running Linux on ARM target board. I want to device a power on self test to detect if the speaker is playing the sound.
Please suggest if it can be done programmatically, as just a return value from loaded sound module does not confirm this always.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`sox stats ..` seems to be one way to detect the levels, assuming you have the option to run `sox`.

i.e.

1. Use software (sox?) to sample the sound output of the ARM target board,
   this might require the use of a special cable, if not a microphone.
2. Run `sox stats ...` on the resulting sound file.

[sox manpage](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

---

For a lower level of requirements: a simplistic level detector built on an op-amp, with level averaging and trigger level sample and hold might be possible to build from a few components.